# Como obtener el estado de varios Switch Button en react

Tags: reactjs

lo que pasa es que genero una vista de varios switch button para poder seleccionar los permisos de cada usuario en el sistema y pues evidentemente para hacer la actualización, necesito obtener el estado de cada uno para poder mostrarle a mis usuarios que el permiso fue activado. Agradezco su ayuda y comentarios.

```
    const encuentraPermiso = (e, idPermiso) => {
  this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });

  self.props
    .getData(
      "miruta"
    )
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.data.response === "ok") {
        console.log(permisos[e.target]);
      }
    });

  alert(
    "El estado del btn presionado es: " +
      e.target.checked +
      " y se llama: " +
      e.target.name +
      " y tiene el id: " +
      idPermiso
  );
};
```